# How to Run or execute EntityFramework.CodeTemplates.CSharp

Tags: .net, visual-studio, entity-framework, c#-4.0, entity-framework-6

I have never used t4 templates, I have downloaded these and made a slight change. How is it I go about running these and can update my local so when I create a new EF DataModel I can choose these?

I have made some headway, the input params are as such

```
<#@ parameter type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbModel" name="Model" #>
<#@ parameter type="System.String" name="Namespace" #>
<#@ parameter type="System.String" name="ContextClassName" #>
<#@ parameter type="System.String" name="ConnectionStringName" #>
```

I need to figure out how to generate
System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbModel
that i believe is my missing piece